# Is the set of positive definite matrices with trace one an open subset of hermitian matrices?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, spectrahedra

Is the set of positive definite matrices with trace one an open subset of hermitian matrices?

I know the set of positive definite matrices is open, but I don't know how to prove that the trace one condition won't affect openness.

Comment: That set is called **spectraplex**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't open. If $A$ is a positive definite matrix with trace $1$, then $A+tI$ is also positive definite for every $t>0$.